# Complex Analysis Problem:

Tags: complex-analysis

By considering the product (2+i)(3+i), show that

(pi/4)=arctan(1/2) + arctan(1/3)?

I tried finding the product of (2+i)*(3+i)=(5+5i). However, I am stuck and do not know what to do from here.

Comment: Well, you probably know the definition of $Arg$, which satisfies the property that $Arg(z) + Arg(w) = Arg(zw)$. The rest follows since $\arctan(1) = \pi/4$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compute Arg(2+i), Arg(3+i) and Arg(5+5i).